# GitLab pipeline execute a job when a cache not available

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

We use GitLab pipeline and try to implement the cache mechanism to avoid the node packages getting downloaded multiple times in a pipeline through different jobs. Our scenario is below

1. The pipeline should check for the availability of cache in the local cache directory
2. if found , then it should download the files and move further with Sonarqube scan
3. If not found, then the pipeline should execute a specific job which do `npm install` and once its finished it should move further with sonarqube scan.

As far as I verified the documents , I didn't see any option to run a specific job only when there is no cache available in the local cache location. Any suggestions?